# How to get a number of related products within a product

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I need to write a query , to count the number of related products. 
I have tried that, but didnt work:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      title: "bike"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        related: "$related",
        inside: "$inside"
      },
      related: {
        $sum: "$inside"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I need to get the number of items inside , table looks like that

```
{
   "title" : "bike",
   "related" : {
       "inside" : [ 
           "item1", 
           "item2", 
           "item3",         
       ]
   }
}
```

Any ideas how to get that number of items inside "bike" -> "inside"?

Comment: Do you want to run any aggregation or just add that number to every existing document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the operator you're looking for is [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/). You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) to add that value to every document:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { title: "Watch" }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            size: { $size: "$related.viewed" }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ka6zd3YhajC)

Comment: I have got more data than I showed in the post, so it needs to be looking for a title 'Watch', because I want the $size of related.viewed only for that item

Comment: Is it also possible, so the query returns only the number?

Comment: So do you want the number of all `related.viewed` from all the documents that have `title: Watch`?

Comment: @Menor please try that new query and let me know if that's what you need